# ObservedResults is empty when using it in the body RealmSync SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, realm

I'm having issues after changing the Realm to a Sync Realm Db, when using the local realm it was working well, the issue here is that I'm using an ObservedResults object and passing it to the custom picker view to display the content of the results, if I print the content in the init of the first view, I can see the data but when I pass it to the custom Picker View the array is empty.

This is when I'm getting the result with the ObservedResults

```
@ObservedResults(AccountType.self) var accountTypes
```

When I print the results in the init it prints the data correctly

```
print("Account Types: \(accountTypes), Count: \(accountTypes.count)")
```

Here I'm mapping the data from the results to pass it into the custom picker view, here is the issue, the result at this point is empty, any thoughts?

```
CustomPickerView(itemIndex: $accountTypeIndex, items: accountTypes.map { return $0.typeDescription }, length: accountTypes.count, pickerName: Constants.accountTypePicker, offsetX: -95)
```

Comment: There could be a number of things causing the issue. If I understand, `accountTypes` is correctly populated should by the `print` statement. However, it's unclear how CustomPickerView is implemented; e.g. what is this `$0.typeDescription`? Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'm mapping the array to send an array of String to the CustomPickerView, so $0.typeDescription is that I'm taking the typeDescription property from the AccountType object.

Comment: Again, there's really not enough information in the question to fully understand the issue. We don't know what is being done with this `accountTypes.map { return $0.typeDescription }` or how it's implemented so that could be the issue... or not.